# Small rectangle in bottom right of image editor

Tags: texture-painting

What does the small rectangle in the bottom right of image editor represent?
[image: Image editor with a small rectangle]

Comment: it may be a face of your UV

Comment: if you provide your blend file...we can tell you the reason exactly.... ;)

Comment: Thanks for those comments. It very likely was a UV. I've recreated the object and made sure it doesn't have any texture mappings applied. Now the little rectangle is gone!